# How to proprely use for loop to get db data

Tags: go, go-templates

I am stuck on a problem with templates, as I don't really get it how it works yet.

My project is a support ticket system, and I am trying to get all entries from db. In this case I am using BoltDB.

The problem is, when I create a for loop, everything in html file also will be "inside" of this loop.

How can I proprely code, in the way to show the entries without duplicate my html?

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type ManageTicketsPage struct {
    Nome    string
    Chamado string
}

func ManageTicketsHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //Pick all tickets from boltdb.
    entries := system_db_listTable(sysdb, "tickets")
    results := [][]string{[]string{
        "Chamado",
        "Nome do Operador",
        "Ativo Retorno",
        "Ativo Saida",
        "Status",
        "Data da Solicitação",
        "Atualizado em",
    }}
    for _, thisTicket := range entries {
        ticketObjectJson := thisTicket[1]
        thisTicketObject := new(ticket)
        err := json.Unmarshal(ticketObjectJson, &thisTicketObject)

        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        thisCSVLine := []string{
            thisTicketObject.Nome,
            thisTicketObject.AtivoCPU,
            thisTicketObject.AtivoSaida,
            thisTicketObject.Status,
            thisTicketObject.DataEntrada,
            thisTicketObject.SubmissionTime.Format("02/01/2006 15:04"),
        }

        Nome := thisTicketObject.Nome
        Chamado := thisTicketObject.AtivoCPU

        p := ManageTicketsPage{Nome: Nome, Chamado: Chamado}

        log.Println(Nome)
        results = append(results, thisCSVLine)
        t, _ := template.ParseFiles("web/admin/tickets.html")
        t.Execute(w, p)
        //log.Println(Nome)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably better to create a Ticket struct, unmarshal into a slice of Ticket, render only once passing in that slice and use range in the template.